# GeoIP2 Javascript ONLY redirecting to else but not specific countries

Tags: javascript, maxmind

The following GeoIP2 javascript is ONLY redirecting to the "else" URL regardless of country/location. It isn't redirecting to the correct URL for that country but instead just sending all traffic to the "else" URL... what have I done wrong and how can I fix it?

```html
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
geoip2.country(
    function (response) {

        if (response.country.iso_code == "AU") {
            window.location = "http://track.cpapower.net/tiny/nEZJp?transid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&_ocid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&offerid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "CO") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/coweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "DE") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/demob.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "EC") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/ecweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "FR") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/frweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "ES") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/esweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "KE") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/keweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "MX") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/mxweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "MY") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/myweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "NL") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/nlweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "PT") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/myweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "RO") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/myweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "SG") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/myweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        if (response.country.iso_code == "ZA") {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/myweb.php?sid=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid"]); ?>&sid2=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid2"]); ?>&sid3=<?php echo str_replace("-", " ", $_GET["sid3"]); ?>"
        }

        else {
            window.location = "http://funloadia.com/whatsapp/"
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is you have `if` conditions and `else` at the end, which will be executing in any case, so try using `if..elseif..else`, as:

```
if (response.country.iso_code == "AU") {
    window.location = ". . . ";
}
else if (response.country.iso_code == "CO") {
    window.location = ". . .";
}
. . .
else {
    window.location = "http://funloadia.co..";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed this. I needed to add "else" in front of "if" for the other countries! Just like in GeoIP1